# What can I do to stop getting some 'local unbound' error message?

Tags: python

I am getting an error saying `"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'numberOfTripsCompleted' referenced before assignment"`

```
trips= 0
def increasetrips(x):
    trips += 1
```

so I construct a list: ['driver', firstname, lastname,vehicletype, trips]. 
After instantiating this with an example: ['driver', Bob, Brown, truck, 0], I now want to have a function to increase the 'trips' part of the list by 1 each time. The function I have above does not give an error, but it after running ' increasetrips', when I call back for my instantiated list, position 4 still holds '0'. So it keeps returning ['driver', Bob, Brown, truck, 0], when i am expecting ['driver', Bob, Brown, truck, 1]

Comment: That code does not contain any variable named `numberOfTripsCompleted`.  Please post the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
trips= 0
def increasetrips(trips):
     trips += 1
     return trips
trips = increasetrips(trips)
```

The parameter `x` you are passing inside the function. And then using `trips` which  is defined outside the function

Comment: i get a typeerror when i try this. thanks though

Comment: That runs perfectly fine for me. Though I have made some changes which will help you understand the flow.

Comment: Thanks. It' s still not incrementing though :-( I have updated the question to make my problem clearer. You may check it out if you wish. Thanks